# C# Do something if int value has incremented/increased by 5 or specific value

Tags: c#

Was wondering if it's possible to do something if the int value was incremented by 5 or specific value? If so, how can it be done?

Like for example:

```
int intExample = 0;

if(intExample has incremented/increased by 5 or specific value) {

doSomething();

}
```

As long as it's increasing by 5 or specific value it will then call the doSomething() method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: of course... with Properties

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can you possibly give an example? Will surely appreciate it alot!

Comment: Have you done any research into this? Properties are a very basic C# feature and can achieve this in an incredibly simple manner.

Comment: Search for Property and INotifyPropertyChanged. What you want is the same pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a field will be difficult but using a property you control the getter and setter separately and can handle events before they happen. Here's an example on difference of 5 and specific value of 99.

```
public class Foo
{
    private int intExample = 0;
    public int IntExample 
    {
        get { return intExample ; }
        set 
        {
            // if the value trying to be set is 5 lower or higher or is 99 call the method
            if((value == intExample - 5) ||
               (value == intExample + 5) ||
               (value == 99))
            {
                DoSomething();
            }

            // set the value in the private field
            intExample = value;
        }
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

and example of how to use it is

```
// create the class
Foo foo = new Foo();

// set value of 32, this will change it but will not trigger as the default is 0 and is not 5 higher or lower or value of 99
foo.IntExample = 32;

// this will trigger as it's 5 more
foor.IntExample = 37;
```

Comment: This is what I am exactly looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Properties with EventEmmitters

```
private int _prop1;

//#1
public event System.EventHandler PropertyChanged;

//#2
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged()
{ 
     if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this,EventArgs.Empty); 
}

public int Prop1
{
    get
    {
         return _prop1;
    }

    set
    {
         //#3
         _prop1=value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
    }
 }
```